# Unlimited values for 2 combined fields

Tags: 7

I want to add 3 fields to my articles:

- `repeatable` (boolean)

  - unlimited values for `repeat_date` and `repeat_comment`

I created the fields and with fields dependency I made the it possible that `repeat_date` and `repeat_comment` only appear if `repeatable` is checked. I can also create an unlimited number of values for `repeat_date` and `repeat_comment`.

But these 2 fields are independet of another. I could create 2 values of `repeat_date` entries and 4 values of `repeat_comment`. Also those fields appear separate when editing articles.

How can I combine those 2 fields and have unlimited values for this combined fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module since I had it  already installed. I created such collection containing 2 fields: `repeat_date` and `repeat_comment`.
Then I made the collection itself unlimited repeatable.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the fields in a Paragraph with the [paragraphs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs). I.e. create a new paragraph type, *repeatable_date*, with two fields: date and comment. Then add a new paragraphs reference field to your article and set cardinality to unlimited. This will allow you to add unlimited repeatable date items, each with date and comment.

Or you can create a new custom field type that has a date field and a comment field. This is more difficult to do, but may be preferable if the paragraphs route doesn't suit you. See [How to create a new field type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140517/how-to-create-new-field-type) for details.